# How to run callback function after firebase service function succeeded in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have firebase service class named `FirebaseSvc`, I am using it in a component named `Register`. What I want to do is to run a reducer function as callback of the firebase `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function.

FirebaseSvc.js user creation function:

```
createAccount = async (user, success_callback, failed_callback) => {
    await firebase.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
        .then(success_callback, failed_callback);
}
```

Register.js submit user registration form:

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    const value = this._form.getValue();

    axios.post(Api.API_URL + 'user', {
        'user': this._form.getValue()
    })
    .then((response) => {
        const user_credentials = { email: response.data.user.email, password: value.password };

        if (response.status === 200) {
            firebaseSvc.fetchingSignInMethodsForEmail(
                user_credentials, 
                function(){
                    console.log('register success');
                    this.props.navigation.state.params.addUser(response.data.user);
                    this.props.navigation.state.params.addCoupledUsers(response.data.extra_data.coupled_users);
                    console.log('trying to navigate to homescreen');
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
                },
                function(){
                    console.log('register failed');
                }
            );
            
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.config);
    });
}
```

after the user successfully registered, I got this message in the console log `register success`, then it gives me an error saying:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)
>
> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing a few things that could be done to fix your error:

1. Use an arrow function for your callback to properly bind `this` to your component instance.

Replace this function:

```
function() {
    console.log('register success');
    this.props.navigation.state.params.addUser(response.data.user); this.props.navigation.state.params.addCoupledUsers(response.data.extra_data.coupled_users);
    console.log('trying to navigate to homescreen');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
}
```

with

```
() => {
    console.log('register success');
    this.props.navigation.state.params.addUser(response.data.user);
    this.props.navigation.state.params.addCoupledUsers(response.data.extra_data.coupled_users);
    console.log('trying to navigate to homescreen');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
}
```

2. Error in `firebaseSvc.fetchingSignInMethodsForEmail` are currently not reaching in the `.catch` method, thus you see `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)`.

To fix this add `return` before `firebaseSvc.fetchingSignInMethodsForEmail`

```
return firebaseSvc.fetchingSignInMethodsForEmail(
                user_credentials, 
...
```